# Non-iterative way to compute mean time until a random event within a limited window?

Tags: st.statistics

Let's say I'm selling widgets, which people have the right to return if they are defective.

Consider that the probability of a particular widget returned on any particular day after its sale is $ p $ (ie. its equally likely to be returned on any day after its sale).  Obviously a given widget can only be returned once.  Given p, I know I can calculate the expected time until an item is returned as follows:

With probability p, T=1. (The return happens tomorrow.) If it doesn't happen tomorrow, then we expect to wait the same amount of time starting then. This gives us:

$ E(T) = p + (1-p)(E(T)+1) $

And we can solve for $E(T)$ to get:

$ E(T) = 1/p $

However, what if if I don't accept returns after N days, and people know this so even if they want to return after N days - they won't even try (so I don't know that a return would have occurred).

The problem is that I want to come up with a way to estimate $p_n$ given an actual duration of time until a return is received - $ d_n $.

My eventual goal is to come up with an overall estimate $ P $ by taking the mean of a variety of values $ p_1, p_2, ... $ I get for a number of independent widget returns.

Now I realize it may be preferable to take the mean of $ d_1, d_2, ... $ and calculate $ P=1/D $ from that, but some external constraints prevent me from taking that approach, I have to take the mean of the probabilities, the $ p_N $ values.

With no return window this is easy, we just reverse $ E(T) = 1/p $, to get (where $d$ is the observed duration until a return): $p=1/d$.

Now the question: If I don't get a return within the $ N $ day time window, meaning that I don't know the actual return duration, but I know its greater than $ N $, what $  p $ value do I use to update my mean, to account for this observation?

Could it be $ p=0 $?

Comment: Note, sorry if this question looks familiar, it is a reformulation of a question I asked yesterday, but which I realized contained a fundamental error, with some additions.

Comment: $T$ is a geometric random variable. If $T$ is the time you get your first ticket then $Pr(T=k) = (1-p)^{k-1} p$, and the prob. you don't get a ticket in $N$ days is $(1-p)^N$. It's not clear how you define $E(T)$ for a fixed $N$. Do you mean $E(T|T\leq N)$?


Comment: I will attempt to rewrite the question to clarify.

Comment: Ok, question completely re-written, would appreciate it if you could take a fresh look

Comment: So you deleted the other question? Thereby disappearing the work of those who tried to help you? Last time I ever answer a question of yours here. Better would have been to have left that question up with an edit explaining what was wrong and pointing readers to this new question. 

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you've got data and want to estimate $p$. This looks straightforward. $T$ is a 'truncated' geometric r.v. with $Pr(T=k) = (1-p)^{k-1} p$ for $k=1,..,N$ and, say, $Pr(T=N+1) = (1-p)^N$  - where $N+1$ marks that you didn't get a return on the first $N$ days. Now, given an observation of $T$ (the $i$-th day of return, where $i$ can be $1,..,N$, or $N+1$ indicating that there was no return), you want to estimate $p$. You can take the maximum likelihood estimator and indeed, if there was no return, the MLE will give you $p=0$.

I don't understand what do you mean by $p_1,p_2,..$. Do you just have different data points with the same $p$? in this case you need to maximize the overall likelihood, and for $n$ different times $d_1,..,d_n$ you get $\hat{p}= (n-r) / (\sum_{i=1}^n d_i - r)$ where $r$ is the number of times there were no returns. Or are you trying to estimate different $p_i$'s?